# Facebook: Is it possible to publish to a user's stream as if from the application itself?

Tags: facebook

Using **stream.publish**, I've tried the above by passing the application's id as the `uid` parameter, but it always gives me a `Permissions Error`. I've ensured that the extended permissions for "publish_stream" are set to allow, but it still gives me this error.

Is it possible to make posts appear as if they came from the application?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to this.  The easiest way to get your app to publish something is to use something like:

```
Facebook.streamPublish("I used this app")
```

This will prompt the user to update their status with the message "I used this app".  This does not require any additional permissions and the final message contains a box saying it came via your app.

Comment: Thanks tim! This will definitely work, but in my scenario I will need to publish to the stream when a user isn't using facebook (updates to data via methods outside of facebook). I need my application to be able to push messages to the stream by itself. Is this possible?

Comment: It is counter to Facebook policies to pre-populate the user message for stream stories.  See http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Policy_Examples_and_Explanations/Stream_Stories

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine if the user has given you extended permissions for offline access (which you can ask for when you request stream publishing permissions as well).  More about that here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions

Once the user has given you offline access, you'll get a session key that doesn't expire, and you can use that to make calls on their behalf.

**UPDATE**: This is no longer necessary, given the end of offline permissions, as @Marty McVry notes.  Even easier!

Comment: Actually, offline access is removed... Long-lived access tokens are now used [FB Developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)